# How to Connect GitHub Repository to google App Engine.?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, developer-console

i am new in android and i am using google app engine as a server .i want to connect my GitHub repository to My Developer console so i can see my server side logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need GitHub to view logs - go [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs) to view your logs.
I also highly recommend you to read this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer).